# Legend and label not rendering on svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am creating a visualisation using d3.js and svg images in PowerBi (this uses version 3 of d3).

I have got my visual working, however my legend is not rendering. I tested this in a browser, and the legend items appear in the elements of the page, but just aren't showing up.

[image]

My code for the legend items are

```
var pbi = {
  width:1108,
  height:636,
  colors:[
    "#A70240",
    "#4A2366",
    "#009A44",
    "#A0D081",
    "#01B5BB",
    "#137B88",
    "#5D6771",
    "#CDC8C1"
  ]

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 140},
    width = pbi.width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = pbi.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    legendleft = pbi.width - margin.right;

 var ly = d3.scale.ordinal() // For legend
      .rangeRoundBands([0, height], barPad, barOuterPad);


var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

----

ly.domain(rData.map(function(d) { return d.milestone; }));  // Legend

var milestoneMap = {};  // Maps years to colours
var legendArray = [];   // For legend

rData.forEach(function (d) {
  var entry = d.year;
  var rowEntry = {
    entry: entry,               // Axis label
    milestone: d.milestone,      // For colour lookup
    date: d.date,               // For X position of points
    y: y(entry)
  }

  if (!(d.milestone in milestoneMap)) {
    // First occurrence of each year saved to legend 
    legendArray.push({milestone: d.milestone});
    rowArray.push(rowEntry);

var legend = svg.append("g").attr("id", "legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + legendleft + "," + margin.top + ")").selectAll(null)
      .data(legendArray)
    .enter();
  
    // Legend agency labels
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("class", "milestoneLabel")
      .attr("x", 25)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return ly(d.milestone)+5; })
      .style("stroke",  "black")
      .style("stroke-width", .3)
      .text(function(d) { return d.milestone; });

  legend.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("cx", 12)
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return ly(d.milestone); })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return milestoneMap[d.milestone]; });
```

This is omitting code that calculates all other elements.

Why is it that the legend circle and label is appearing as an element on the page but isn't rendering anything?

Thanks

Comment: without seeing more of your code, I'd guess that your SVG isn't actually that large so the elements are in the DOM but outside the bounds of the SVG and therefore not visible but still inspectable.

Comment: @AndrewReid I have amended my question to include the code regarding my margins and svg creation. I'm assuming by your comment the issue is in the var svg line?

Comment: @AndrewReid I figured it out! Just had to add 'legend left' to my svg width. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just needed to add my `legend left` to my svg.

From

```js
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

to

```js
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + legendleft)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```